# Chrome Dev Tools not triggering media queries?

Tags: google-chrome, media-queries, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using some simple media queries below.  When I went to test them using the Chrome Dev Tools they did not work.  I tried using the "responsive" mode and resizing as well as using predefined layouts for common mobile devices.  I tested in 67.0.3396.99 and 69.0.3480.0 (Canary).

```
.server-view {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 499px) {
    .server-view {
        left: 0;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .server-view {
        left: 250px;
    }
}
```

If I close the debug tools and just resize the browser window, the content changes as expected.

Is this a bug or something I'm doing wrong somehow?  I swear I've tested like this before, but now I'm wondering if I need to change my workflow.  I spent at least 10 minutes debugging only to figure it out actually works outside of dev tools...

These media queries are in a `LESS` file if it matters.  I also tried `@media all` with the same results.

Comment: Came in today and both browsers are working as expected.  I haven't rebooted.  No updates.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I was having this issue. I usually use em rather than px, but in this case I was using px and didn't realize I was zoomed in a little. I think the zoom and use of px was causing this discrepancy for myself at least.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, restarting Chrome didn't resolve. I am simultaneously running my web app locally in two ways: 1) compiled by webpack, served via Apache and use a real URL (via hosts file) where the media query works fine, and 2) using webpack-dev-server and URL is localhost:8080 where the media query is not working. The same is true in firefox: when the URL is localhost:8080, the media queries are not working.